# How to develop application for CASIO DTX30 on .Net?

Tags: .net, pushdown-automaton

How to develop application for CASIO DTX30 on .Net ?

Comment: `enter code here`? Is this an online test?

Comment: @GSerg, there's no such thing as *default question template*.

Comment: @GSerg: If you click the `{}` above the textbox without selection, you get that. I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

You need Visual Studio 2008 for that (Professional of higher). Support for Windows CE programming was removed from Visual Studio 2010 and later.

Using VS2008, create a new Smart Device project.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by GSerg, you'll need Visual Studio 2008 to develop for the DT-X30.

In addition I'd recommend the following:

The [Casio Developers/Partners](http://partners.casio.co.uk/mtddevelopers/) page (requires registration and log in) will allow you to access the SDK and other downloads. I believe there is a software developers guide available and downloading the SDK will give you access to some great sample applications.

[This page](http://www.casio-b2b.com/mis/euro/faq/?branchid=a97da629b098b75c294dffdc3e463904) on the casio-b2b website will allow you access to some documentation and patches also.